# ngrx/rxjs: can this code to first check the store and then do the API request be improved?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

Before fetching new data from the backend, I'm first checking if it's in the store already, and I do take care that the store is always synced every time there's an update.

To do so, my `effect` does the following:

```
@Effect()
LoadImage: Observable<LoadImageSuccess> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AppActionTypes.LOAD_IMAGE),
  withLatestFrom(action => this.store$.select(selectImage, action.payload).pipe(map(result => ({ action, result })))),
  switchMap(observable => observable),
  mergeMap(({ action, result }) =>
    result !== null
      ? of(result).pipe(map(image => new LoadImageSuccess(image)))
      : this.imageApiService.getImage(action.payload).pipe(
          map(image => new LoadImageSuccess(image)),
          catchError(error => EMPTY)
        )
  )
);
```

This seems to work fine, but I wonder if it can be made nicer:

1. The `switchMap(observable => observable),` doesn't look very nice.
2. Would the condition in the `mergeMap` be better handled via a `iif`?
3. When two components dispatch a `LOAD_IMAGE` action, my API call is still happening twice, because the first request hasn't completed yet (and hasn't put the image in the store) when the second request starts. This is not a common occurrence with images on my website, but might be with other components in the future and I wonder if there's a way to improve this.

Thanks!

Please note, if I remove the `switchMap(observable => observable),`, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

The object that gets passed to the `mergeMap` if I comment out the `switchMap`, is of type `Store`:

[image: Object after withLatestFrom]

**EDIT**:

Based on the accepted answer, this is what I ended up with:

```
@Effect()
LoadImage: Observable<LoadImageSuccess> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(AppActionTypes.LOAD_IMAGE),
  mergeMap(action =>
    this.store$.select(selectImage, action.payload).pipe(
      mergeMap(imageFromStore =>
        imageFromStore !== null
          ? of(imageFromStore).pipe(map(image => new LoadImageSuccess(image)))
          : this.imageApiService.getImage(action.payload).pipe(
              map(image => new LoadImageSuccess(image)),
              catchError(error => EMPTY)
            )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Why is that switchMap even in there..?

Comment: @MikeOne because the `withLatestFrom` above it returns an `Observable<{LoadImageSuccess, Image}>`.

Comment: The mergeMap below will also subscribe to that..?

Comment: @MikeOne I edited the question to show what happens if I remove that `switchMap`.

Comment: Yes that is expected. You’ll get an array there now. Remove the destructure with ‘data’ or something and console it.

Comment: @MikeOne I updated the question, please see at the end. The thing I get in the `mergeMap` is of type `Store`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the arg passed to `withLatestFrom` is the [projection function](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/withLatestFrom.ts#L59), so that's why you have to resort to the `switchMap` hack.

If you need to check based on the current action, I think you'd be better off doing it with something like this:

```js
ofType(...),

// do the check
switchMap(
  action => this.store.select(...)
    .pipe(
      ...,
    // act based on the check's result
    // decided to nest this as a response to question 3
    // since if multiple calls are made at the same time, only the last one will be good to go
    switchMap(({ action, result }) => ...)
  )
),
```